# Image preview or expand option after it is posted

Tags: feature-request, images, markdown-preview

It's great that we are able to post images to stackoverflow but sometimes we are posting images that actually have a bigger size and by default from what I noticed stackoverflow will fit the image on the layout by resizing its properties.

I would like to request a simple preview ability from posted images when they are bigger than the resized size.

For instance you post a 1920x1200 image and it gets resized to 100x200 (not actual used sized but just example) then we have a click here to show real size or anything alike that allows us to see the image in its actual size if it is bigger then what it shows.

**Here is an example of what I meant:**
http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/

Here is an 1920x1200 image example ;) and if u go to https://i.stack.imgur.com/kca25.jpg you will be able to so it in full size but we have no options here to actually view it in full size so we have to copy the url and follow it to actually see wether it goes bigger or not.

[image: 1920x1200 image example]

Comment: Right-click -> "Open/View image in new tab"

Comment: @Cody Gray in some browsers yes but still it is not as simple as a click.

Comment: No, it doesn't work properly in Lynx. Can't imagine that's a huge problem, though.

Comment: @Cody nor old ie's, but that's not what I am pointing out here, you dont even know if the image i posted above has a higher resolution or not so in first place you would probably never attempt to open it in a new tab just to verify that so if we have a enlarge option when mouse goes over or perhaps a border that says it can be enlarged it would possible call more attention and help in cases where people do upload images with a big proportions.

Comment: In how many cases is it really practical to post a screen capture of your *entire* desktop? (I'm thinking once a year, tops.) I oppose the needless visual clutter, and more importantly, the possibility that I accidentally click on it.

Comment: @Cody I never said that people need to post their entire desktop but images are capped to 640px I think and having bigger images in this case considering peoples resolution is pretty common. I don't really see why having a enlarge option on the images would be a bad feature to stackoverflow considering that you are allowed to upload any image size you want even tought the layout is limited it doesnt mean we can't have an enlarge option or something that tells the image is bigger or a link to the actual image.

Comment: +1 resize, -1 lightbox. Not a fan of the lightbox experience.

Comment: @sixlettervariables lightbox was not a demand was just a way to show an example of what I meant here, which is the resize option.

Comment: @Prix: Gotcha, so something like clicking makes it Open in full size. I am for any suggestion that does not bring the image up over the page. I usually follow @Cody's suggestion.

Comment: @sixlettervariables any way stackoverflow community / staff judges is good to go and allow us to browse the full image with a simple click without having to leave the question. I guess in resume that is it but correct if i am wrong ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I totally agree with this. As an example, here is a diagram I've posted [Preventing FIN_WAIT2 when closing socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328155/preventing-fin-wait2-when-closing-socket/5328376#5328376) about the TCP connection states.

It would be very practical to be able to click on the image to read the text correctly. I'm not sure all users are very familiar with the `r-click > View image` process.

So having a magnify icon in the corner of the down-resized picture with a expand on click view could be nice.

Think of a system like [Google's one](https://plus.google.com/photos/106956299875722921838/albums/5624056415793872081?hl=en)

Comment: Pretty sure everyone on Stack Overflow is familiar with right-clicking to view an image. I don't think this is too much to expect across the rest of the network, either. We're primarily targeting Internet-savvy users.

Answer (score 2):

Third [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) so far that gets solved by my script ^.^

Use the following script:

[Thumbnail Uploader](https://stackapps.com/q/3507/10098)

With the options "normal size" (or "large" if you want to save some bandwidth) and "link to full size".

[image: enter link description here]

It'll create a nifty thumbnail for you :)

I plan on adding an option where the image is appended with "click to enlarge" if you so wish. The script auto-updates, so you'll automatically get the feature when I push it.

Comment: I am looking forward to a stackoverflow solution not a 3rd party, hope you understand.

Comment: @Prix: I understand--this isn't meant to be a _final_ answer. It's a workaround till this gets implemented. Many feature requests take a long time to get attention, this one probably will as well. My post is to help you in the meantime.

Comment: :P I appreciate your effort but its not up to me to do that. My concern was related to everyone else that posts images that you can't view because of it, hence making you the extra trouble that I mentioned above.

Comment: @Prix: Every drop makes an ocean. :)

Answer (score 1):

I understood your request to be "please provide a means of resizing large images before posting."

Here is a quick answer:

I will be pushing some changes to my [Freehand Circle Script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor-now-supported-on-every-st) within the next day or two that will do exactly what you've described - it will allow you to resize an image before posting it or even after it has been posted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is not about the upload, it is about it being able to preview images like lightbox2 when they are large than the defaul layout. You can see that from the image i posted it is 1920x1200 but meta resized it to fit the layout and we have no options to enlarge it but manually doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree completly. In my opinion, either auto-generate something like

```
<a href="URL_HERE" target="_blank">IMAGE_HERE</a>
```

or use [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)/[fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).

So far, I've just uploaded the image and added `<sub>[link](link)</sub>` below the image, but it's a workaround for something that shouldn't need a workaround.