# Auto-link images that have been auto-shrunken to fit on the page

Tags: feature-request, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image preview or expand option after it is posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90054/image-preview-or-expand-option-after-it-is-posted)

When you post an image as part of your question or answer and it's too big to fit on the page, it is simply given a width and height to be resized by the browser, but the original full-size image is still there.  Example:

[image: this is a super huge image]

Might it be worth having the system automatically convert these into links to the image so you can click on it and see the full-size image?